# Notify listview in fragment when action done in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I add items in database and show in `listview` (tab 1), in the next `fragment` (tab 2) there is `togglebutton`.If `togglebutton` `.ischecked` and if condition is meet ,`textView` in the `listView` will change its color, but this happens only when I scroll the list view. How do I notify List Data Adapter that I have made changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface in your fragment and implement it in the listview fragment.

```
public interface ToggleListener{
    void onToggled(boolean toggle);
}
```

and when you press the toggleButton, you use

```
toggleListener.onToggled(toggleState)
```

Then in the activity fragment implement this interface and Override the onToggled function

```
 @Override
 public void onToggled(boolean toggle){
   //your code here
 }
```

If your listView is in a fragment then you can create an interface in the Main Activity and implement it in the listView fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use EventBus or other bus-like component, you can post the event to the subscriber in your tab1.